# Which rotations are positive and negative in y-z plane?

Tags: geometry

Why is it considered that in x-y plane counterclockwise movements are positive and clockwise are negative? And in x-z plane it is vice versa? How can I know which movements are positive and negative in y-z plane or in higher dimensional spaces? Is there any relationship?

Comment: I think it has more to do with convention of the form of 3-D cartesian co-ordinate systems. If you try to put your right palm(wrist to fingers) along say x-axis and close it (keeping your thumb outstretched) trying to catch y axis, your thumb would point along the defined k cap or +ve z direction. Most books however they may represent/arrange these axis in space there mutual configuration follows this convention. Hope this helps...

Comment: @pi-die-die Thanks. I didn't quite understand how the thumb rule works. In x-z and x-y planes we go from x to y and z. And in y-z plane what is the origin and the ending point?

Comment: Its done serially if you apply rule from x to y you get your thumb along z. Similarly if you go from y to z then your thumb would go along x. And finally if you curl your right hand from z to x you get thumb along y... just remember xyzxyzxyzxyz...or google cross product in cartesian 3-D.    P.S- the origin doesn't matter just put your right palm along an axis and curl it to catch the other axis while keeping your thumb outstreched...